# Add exclusion to Doctrine Query Builder in JOIN

Tags: postgresql, symfony, join, doctrine, dql

I have built the following query with the Doctrine Query Builder in my Symfony application.

```
    $qb->select('c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Course', 'c')
        ->join('AppBundle:Log', 'a', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('c.id', 'a.course'))
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('a.type', ':type'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('a.time', ':start', ':end'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('c.status', ':status'))
        ->setParameter(':type', ['opened'])
        ->setParameter(':standardScratchScore', [74])
        ->setParameter(':status', Course::OPENED)
        ->setParameter(':start', $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter(':end', $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ;
```

In my code I iterate over the `Course`s and then again query the `Log` table to check that an entry with a specific type doesn't exist for the `Course`. Is there a way I can incorporate the exclusion of `log.type = 'log.sent-email'` **for this Course** into this initial query, without using something like a sub-select?

Querying the same table again within the loop feels sub-optimal to me and NewRelic suggests it is hurting the performance of my application.

Comment: Did you try it with a left join with an IS NULL on the result of the join? Something like:
LEFT JOIN log with log.type  = 'log.sent-email'
WHERE log.id IS NULL

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure where this fits in as I am already joining course and log on course.id=log.course_id. I think you are on the right lines with the `IS NULL`, but it's the extra `type` filter I am stumped on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can always join the table one more time for this specific need:

```
$qb->select('c')
    ->from('AppBundle:Course', 'c')
    ->join('AppBundle:Log', 'a', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('c.id', 'a.course'))
    ->leftjoin(
        'AppBundle:Log', 
        'b', 
        Expr\Join::WITH, 
        $qb->expr()->andx(
            $qb->expr()->eq('c.id', 'b.course'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('b.type', 'log.sent-email')
        ))          
    ) // join log a second time, with the type condition
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('a.type', ':type'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('a.time', ':start', ':end'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('c.status', ':status'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('b.type')) // Only select records where no log record is found
    ->setParameter(':type', ['opened'])
    ->setParameter(':standardScratchScore', [74])
    ->setParameter(':status', Course::OPENED)
    ->setParameter(':start', $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->setParameter(':end', $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
;
```

Comment: I think I jumped the gun with accepting this as the answer. Sorry about that. What I am finding is that the `leftjoin` (`b`) is joining on ALL "log.sent-email" entries in that table and not just on the result set of the first join. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong now...

Comment: @crmpicco You are right, my previous statement about not needing to specify the foreign key in the join was incorrect because this is a one to many join. Updated my answer can you check? (it is untested).

Comment: You're a star, mate! I spent WAY too long looking at this. Thanks for the help.